# How can i convert MP3 into PWM?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, mp3, pwm

For a project that I am doing I am trying to essentially convert an mp3 file into vibrations. I have talked to staff at SparkFun Electronics who set me up with the Lilypad Vibe Board and the Arduino Uno. It is in my understanding that with the Arduino Uno its unable to read an MP3 file and convert it into PWM so that the Lilypad Vibe Board can produce the vibrations. Does anyone know if there is any code or another device that will allow me to do this? I have researched the Raspberry Pi but am also unsure as to if this will work in the way i would like it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My aim is to take an mp3 file, convert it into PWM so that the Lilypad Vibe Board would be able to create the vibrations in relation to the mp3 file.

Comment: You mean other than any of their products that *can* decode MP3s?

Comment: Yes! And it has come to my attention that i could possibly use the Arduino Uno in association with a micro SD card. Now on this note would the lilypad vibe board still be able to convert this sound into the vibrations even with the use of the SD card?

Comment: The device doesn't care where the bits come from.

Comment: Great, so just to confirm... I would be able to code an mp3 file which is on the sd card and the sd card shield, it will then go to the arduino uno and will send the message to the lilypad vibe board which will then vibrate accordingly?

Comment: Nothing in that plan actually decodes the MP3 file. You will need something that does so.

Comment: would this work? -- The Sparkfun MP3 Shield? It wires the Arduino up to a VS1053B MP3 audio decoder IC, providing it with the ability to decode audio files. The VS1053 is also capable of decoding Ogg Vorbis/MP3/AAC/WMA/MIDI audio and encoding IMA ADPCM and user-loadable Ogg Vorbis. The VS1053 receives its input bitstream through a serial input bus (SPI). After the stream has been decoded by the IC, the audio is sent out to both a 3.5mm stereo headphone jack, as well as a 2-pin 0.1" pitch header.

Comment: Sure. But you'll need to get the audio from the shield to the Arduino.